# Understanding join order for 3 or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an old query that was using `*=` operator. Right now, the query has where clause like below

```
Table1.Column1 *= Table2.Column1
AND Table1.Column2 *= Table3.Column1
if (some conditions in C# script)  //this whole clause is generated by C# function based on different conditions
AND Table1.Column3 *= Table4.Column1
```

I have to rewrite it to use left join, because well, we are not dinosaurs anymore, and are moving to SQL server 2014 (from sql server 2000). Anyway, I have rewritten the query like

```
From Table1
Left Join Table2 On Table1.Column1 = Table2.Column1
Left Join Table3 On Table1.Column2 = Table3.Column1
Left Join Table4 On Table1.Column3 = Table4.Column1
```

I believe this should provide me the same resultset, but it is not. Clearly SQL Server is not following the same join order in both cases. So, I have to figure out the exact order the old query is following, and how to recreate the same order.

P.S. I don't have much understanding about the code. But, I can post the complete function here, in case if it helps someone understand the situation better.

Edit:

The exact query builder function, I am using.

```
public virtual FANUC.Common.BaseClasses.Row[] GetCustomersForPopup( FANUC.Common.BaseClasses.Row objListCustomerFilter, FANUC.Common.BaseClasses.PagingEventArgs e )    {

        string strConnector = " WHERE ";
        string strANDClause = "";

        string strSQLQuery  = " SELECT "
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_ID,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_Name,"
                            + " " + ( ( FANUCUser )Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity ).DBUser + ".fnGetRefCodeValue( CMPM_Company_Type_ID ) AS CMPM_CompanyTypeID,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_NickName,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Service_Center_ID,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_BranchName,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Black_Listed_Flag,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Prohibited_Company_Flag,"   
                            + " " + ( ( FANUCUser )Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity ).DBUser + ".fnGetRefCodeValue( TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Status ) AS CMPM_Status,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_City_Location_ID AS CMPM_City_Location_ID,"
                            + " TBL_City_Location_Master.CLIM_City_Name AS CLIM_City_Name, "
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Country_ID AS CMPM_Country_ID,"
                            + " TBL_Country_Master.CRIM_CountryName, "
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Night_Call_Applicable_flag,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Default_currency_for_transaction,"
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Telephone_No, "
                            + " TBL_Customer_Contact_Master.CNTM_ContactPersonName, "
                            + " TBL_Customer_Contact_Master.CNTM_Section_Name, "
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.Use_Count, "
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Self_Company_Indicator, "
                            + " TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Transport_Time ";


        string strFromClause    = " FROM TBL_Company_Master, "
                                + " TBL_Service_Center_Master, "
                                + " TBL_City_Location_Master, "
                                + " TBL_Country_Master, "
                                + " TBL_Customer_Contact_Master";

        strANDClause    += " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Service_Center_ID *= TBL_Service_Center_Master.SCRM_Service_Center_ID  "
                        +  " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_City_Location_ID *= TBL_City_Location_Master.CLIM_City_ID "
                        +  " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Country_ID *= TBL_Country_Master.CRIM_CountryID ";

            if ( objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.IS_CALLING_CUSTOMER ] != null || objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.IS_PAYEE_CUSTOMER ] != null || Convert.ToInt32( objListCustomerFilter[ "CUTM_Customer_Type_ID" ] ) == 120 ) 
                strANDClause += " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_ID *= TBL_Customer_Contact_Master.CNTM_Customer_ID ";
            else
                strANDClause += " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_ID = TBL_Customer_Contact_Master.CNTM_Customer_ID " ;

            strANDClause    += " AND TBL_Customer_Contact_Master.CNTM_Default_Flag = 'Y' "; 
            strANDClause    += " AND CMPM_Active_Flag != 'N'";


        if ( objListCustomerFilter["CUTM_Customer_Type_ID"] != null && Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CUTM_Customer_Type_ID"]) != "" ) {
            strFromClause   += " ,TBL_Customer_Type_Mapping ";
            strANDClause    += " AND CUTM_Customer_ID = CMPM_Company_ID " + " AND CUTM_Customer_Type_ID = "+Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CUTM_Customer_Type_ID"]);
        }

        if ( objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_Type_ID"] != null && Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_Type_ID"]) != "" && Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_Type_ID"]) != Constants.ALL )   {
            strANDClause += " AND CMPM_Company_Type_ID IN ("+Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_Type_ID"])+","+Constants.COMPANY_TYPE_BOTH+") ";
        }

        if ( !Convert.ToString( objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.PAYMENT_REQD ] ).Equals(Constants.CONST_NO ) ) {

            strSQLQuery += ", TBL_Company_Payment_Terms.CMPT_Payment_Term_Description "
                        + ", TBL_Company_Payment_Terms.CMPT_Payment_Term_ID ";

            strFromClause += " ,TBL_Company_Payment_Terms ";

            if((objListCustomerFilter[Constants.IS_CALLING_CUSTOMER] != null) ||(objListCustomerFilter[Constants.IS_END_USER] != null) ) 
                strANDClause    += " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_ID *= TBL_Company_Payment_Terms.CMPT_Company_ID "
                                + " AND TBL_Company_Payment_Terms.CMPT_Default = 'Y' ";
            else
                strANDClause    += " AND TBL_Company_Master.CMPM_Company_ID = TBL_Company_Payment_Terms.CMPT_Company_ID "
                                + " AND TBL_Company_Payment_Terms.CMPT_Default = 'Y' ";


            if ( objListCustomerFilter[ "CMPM_Company_Type_ID" ] != null && Convert.ToString( objListCustomerFilter[ "CMPM_Company_Type_ID" ] ) != Constants.COMPANY_TYPE_BOTH && Convert.ToString( objListCustomerFilter[ "CMPM_Company_Type_ID" ] ) != Constants.ALL )
                strANDClause += " AND CMPT_Company_Type_ID = " + Convert.ToString( objListCustomerFilter[ "CMPM_Company_Type_ID" ] );   

        }

        strANDClause += " AND CMPM_Subsidiary_Code = '"+((FANUCUser)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).SubsidiaryCode+"'";

        Row objFilter = new Row();

        objFilter["CMPM_Company_ID"]                            = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Black_Listed_Flag"]                     = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Black_Listed_Flag"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Prohibited_Company_Flag"]               = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Prohibited_Company_Flag"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Status"]                                = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Status"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Company_Name~like"]                     = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_Name"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Company_NickName~like"]                 = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_NickName"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Telephone_No~like"]                     = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Telephone_No"];
        objFilter["CMPM_FAX_No"]                                = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_FAX_No"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Service_Center_ID"]                     = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Service_Center_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Billing_Company_ID"]                    = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Billing_Company_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Shipping_Company_ID"]                   = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Shipping_Company_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_City_Location_ID"]                      = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_City_Location_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_State_ID"]                              = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_State_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Country_ID"]                            = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Country_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Grp_Parent_Company_ID"]                 = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Grp_Parent_Company_ID"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Night_Call_Applicable_Flag"]            = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Night_Call_Applicable_Flag"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Default_currency_for_transaction"]      = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Default_currency_for_transaction"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Company_local_registration_No~like"]    = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_local_registration_No"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Company_central_registration_No~like"]  = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_central_registration_No"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Insurance_Policy_No~like"]              = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Insurance_Policy_No"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Active_Flag"]                           = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Active_Flag"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Company_BranchName~like"]               = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_BranchName"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Company_BranchName_LocalLanguage~like"] = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Company_BranchName_LocalLanguage"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Postal_Code"]                           = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Postal_Code"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Web_Site~like"]                         = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Web_Site"];
        objFilter["CMPM_Distance"]                              = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Distance"];

        if ( objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Self_Company_Indicator"] != null && Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Self_Company_Indicator"]) != Constants.ALL )
            objFilter[ "CMPM_Self_Company_Indicator" ]  = objListCustomerFilter["CMPM_Self_Company_Indicator"];



        CommonBQ    objCommonBQ     = new CommonBQ();
        string      strSearchClause = objCommonBQ.CreateFilter( objFilter );
        string      strFinalString  = "";

        if ( !strSearchClause.Equals( "" ) )    strFinalString  = strSQLQuery + strFromClause + strConnector + strSearchClause + strANDClause;
        else    {

            strSQLQuery += strFromClause + strConnector + strANDClause;

            int     iFirstPos       = strSQLQuery.IndexOf( "AND", 0 );
            string  strFirstPart    = strSQLQuery.Substring( 0, iFirstPos );
            string  strSecondPart   = strSQLQuery.Substring( iFirstPos + 3, strSQLQuery.Length - iFirstPos - 3 );

            strFinalString  = strFirstPart + strSecondPart;
        }

        return  GetRows( strFinalString, CreateParameterArray( objListCustomerFilter ), CommandType.Text, null, e );
    }
```

Comment: I do not understand the question? What output does the first and second give you?

Comment: Please share entire `where` clause..

Comment: New query returns about half the rows of the original one. I will add the full clause in the main comment.

Comment: are you still able to use the older syntax (*=) for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, actually. I still have access to old test server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should update in this query:

1. Use Table Alias in select clause instead of complete table names.
2. `TBL_Customer_Contact_Master` is being joined based on condition:
   objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.IS_CALLING_CUSTOMER ] != null ||
   objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.IS_PAYEE_CUSTOMER ] != null ||
   Convert.ToInt32( objListCustomerFilter[ "CUTM_Customer_Type_ID" ] )
   == 120 )    If this holds true then there's a `Left Join` else `Inner join`.
3. So update the statements as:

   string strFromClause = 
   " FROM TBL_Company_Master TCM " + 
   " Left Join TBL_Service_Center_Master TSC on 
       TCM.CMPM_Service_Center_ID = TSC.SCRM_Service_Center_ID " + 
   "Left Join TBL_City_Location_Master TCL on
       TCM.CMPM_City_Location_ID = TCL.CLIM_City_ID " + 
   "Left Join TBL_Country_Master TC on
       TCM.CMPM_Country_ID = TC.CRIM_CountryID ";
4. Update condition 1 as:

   if ( objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.IS_CALLING_CUSTOMER ] != null ||
    objListCustomerFilter[ Constants.IS_PAYEE_CUSTOMER ] != null || Convert.ToInt32(
    objListCustomerFilter[ "CUTM_Customer_Type_ID" ] ) == 120 )

   strFromClause  += " Left join TBL_Customer_Contact_Master TCCM on TCM.CMPM_Company_ID 
   = TCCM.CNTM_Customer_ID ";
   else
   strFromClause  += " Inner join TBL_Customer_Contact_Master TCCM on TCM.CMPM_Company_ID 
   = TCCM.CNTM_Customer_ID ";
5. Then update condition 2 as:
   if ( objListCustomerFilter["CUTM_Customer_Type_ID"] != null && Convert.ToString
   (objListCustomerFilter["CUTM_Customer_Type_ID"]) != "" ) {

   strFromClause   += "Left join TBL_Customer_Type_Mapping on CUTM_Customer_ID = CMPM_Company_ID AND CUTM_Customer_Type_ID = "+Convert.ToString(objListCustomerFilter["CUTM_Customer_Type_ID"] ; }
6. And condition 3 as:

   if((objListCustomerFilter[Constants.IS_CALLING_CUSTOMER] != null) ||(objListCustomerFilter
   [Constants.IS_END_USER] != null) ) 
   strFromClause += " Left Join TBL_Company_Payment_Terms TCPT 
   On TCM.CMPM_Company_ID = TCPT.CMPT_Company_ID AND TCPT.CMPT_Default = 'Y' ";
   else
   strFromClause += " Inner Join TBL_Company_Payment_Terms TCPT 
   On TCM.CMPM_Company_ID = TCPT.CMPT_Company_ID AND TCPT.CMPT_Default = 'Y' ";

I might have missed a few commas and semi - colons here and there but it should give you an idea where things might be missing. Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks. I guess, I did something stupid. I was just removing the On condition in the if statement. I tried replacing the left join with an inner join, and the output is same. 

Although, I am confused as to why I got less rows. If I use left join, instead of inner join, I should have received more rows, right?

Comment: BTW, if I am adding the On condition, I have to remove the and clause. Just mentioning it for future reference.

Comment: what I can suggest is you create each `strFromClause` condition one by one ie adding one at a time then debug the two solutions.. you will come to know which condition is breaking your code..

Comment: `INNER JOIN` T1 `ON` col1 = col2 `AND` col3= col4 is always a valid statement .. I didn't got what you meant ..

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what was breaking the code. Thankfully, Inner join did the trick. I should have done it in first place, instead of removing the On condition. 

BTW, thanks for the great response. I was expecting to understand the issue, wasn't expecting someone to replace the whole function as is. This just saved me a lot of work.

Comment: `Left Join TBL_Company_Payment_Terms TCPT On TCM.CMPM_Company_ID = TCPT.CMPT_Company_ID ` Consider this statement in condition 3. In else condition, I was just replacing it with `Left Join TBL_Company_Payment_Terms TCPT`. I think that should result in an error, but it didn't. I will never know why it resulted in fewer rows. But whatever. Inner join is a better idea, anyway, and makes more sense to use.

Answer (score 0):

The order doesn't matter in left outer joins so please stay assured, it's not causing it. My guess would be the if statments might be causing the difference in results.
If you can share the table data or the outputs, it could be figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in how additional `where` clause filters are applied for columns in the outer joined tables.

With this:

```
select *
from a
    left outer join b on a.id = b.id
where
    b.other_col = 'test'
```

The result will contain only rows where the row in `b` was found and the `other_col` column in `b` has the value `test`.

Comparing to this:

```
select *
from a, b
where
    a.id *= b.id
    and b.other_col = 'test'
```

This will find all rows in `a`. And it will include the columns from `b` for rows where `b.other_col = 'test'`.

So taking the second query and converting it to one with a left join, one of the following would give the same output:

```
-- 1.

select *
from a
    left outer join b on a.id = b.id and b.other_col = 'test'

-- 2.

select *
from a
    left outer join 
    (
        select *
        from b
        where other_col = 'test'
    ) as b on a.id = b.id
```